vscode Latex-workshop
I've been going through all docs and wikis...
The problem:

Cannot get to compile .tex on vscosde using the Latex-workshop extension

I am using vscode on ubuntu
I can id the location of the pdflatex executable and it is in the $PATH env variable. compilation runs fine on the command line terminal.
Could some other eyes help out to pinpoint what am I doing wrong? or is it a bug in my installation?
any help is kindly appreciated. I will summarize.
Cheers,
The executable path:
horo@XXXX:/usr/local$ which pdflatex
/usr/bin/pdflatex
horo@XXXX:/usr/local$ echo $PATH
/home/horo/.pyenv/shims:/home/horo/.pyenv/bin:/home/horo/.pyenv/bin:/home/horo/.pyenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin:/home/horo/.local/bin

The error:
10:23:25.112][Commander] BUILD command invoked.
[10:23:25.113][Build] The document of the active editor: file://%WS1%/main_HS.tex
[10:23:25.113][Build] The languageId of the document: latex
[10:23:25.113][Root] Current workspace folders: ["file://%WS1%"]
[10:23:25.114][Root] Try finding root from magic comment.
[10:23:25.115][Root] Try finding root from active editor.
[10:23:25.116][Root] Found root file from active editor: %WS1%/main_HS.tex
[10:23:25.117][Root] Keep using the same root file: %WS1%/main_HS.tex
[10:23:25.118][Event] ROOT_FILE_SEARCHED
[10:23:25.118][Event] STRUCTURE_UPDATED
[10:23:25.119][Build] Building root file: %WS1%/main_HS.tex
[10:23:25.119][Build][Recipe] Build root file %WS1%/main_HS.tex
[10:23:25.127][Build][Recipe] Preparing to run recipe: pdflatex -> bibtex -> pdflatex * 2.
[10:23:25.127][Build][Recipe] Prepared 5 tools.
[10:23:25.136][Build][Recipe] outDir: %WS1% .
[10:23:25.137][Build] Recipe step 1 The command is pdflatex:["-synctex=1","-interaction=nonstopmode","-file-line-error","-outdir=%WS1%","%WS1%/main_HS.tex"].
[10:23:25.137][Build] env: {"PATH":"/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"}
[10:23:25.137][Build] root: %WS1%/main_HS.tex
[10:23:25.138][Build] cwd: %WS1%
[10:23:25.143][Build] LaTeX build process spawned with PID 36124.
[10:23:26.153][Parser][TexLog] Logged 147 messages.
[10:23:26.155][Build] Finished a step in recipe with PID 36124.
[10:23:26.155][Build] Recipe step 2 The command is bibtex:["main_HS"].
[10:23:26.155][Build] env: {"PATH":"/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"}
[10:23:26.155][Build] root: %WS1%/main_HS.tex
[10:23:26.155][Build] cwd: %WS1%
[10:23:26.162][Build] LaTeX build process spawned with PID 36128.
[10:23:26.280][Parser][BibTeXLog] Logged 3 messages.
[10:23:26.281][Build] Recipe returns with error code 2/null on PID 36128.
[10:23:26.281][Build] Does the executable exist? $PATH: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin, $Path: undefined, $SHELL: /bin/bash
[10:23:26.282][Build] 
[10:23:26.282][Build] Cleaning auxiliary files and retrying build after toolchain error.
[10:23:26.283][Cleaner] Clean temporary files command The command is latexmk:["-outdir=%WS1%","-c","%WS1%/main_HS.tex"].
[10:23:26.289][Build] Recipe step 2 The command is bibtex:["main_HS"].
[10:23:26.290][Build] env: {"PATH":"/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"}
[10:23:26.290][Build] root: %WS1%/main_HS.tex
[10:23:26.290][Build] cwd: %WS1%
[10:23:26.306][Build] LaTeX build process spawned with PID 36130.
[10:23:26.487][Event] AUTO_CLEANED
[10:23:26.487][Build] Recipe returns with error code 1/null on PID 36130.
[10:23:26.487][Build] Does the executable exist? $PATH: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin, $Path: undefined, $SHELL: /bin/bash
[10:23:26.487][Build] 

I have formatted the settings.json as follows:
    "latex-workshop.latex.recipes": [

      {
        "name": "pdflatex -> bibtex -> pdflatex * 2",
        "tools": [
          "pdflatex",
          "bibtex",
          "pdflatex",
          "pdflatex"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "latexmk",
        "tools": [
          "latexmk"
        ]
      },
    ],
    "latex-workshop.latex.tools": [


      {
        "name": "latexmk",
        "command": "latexmk",
        "args": [
          "-shell-escape",
          "-synctex=1",
          "-interaction=nonstopmode",
          "-file-line-error",
          "-pdf",
          "-outdir=%OUTDIR%",
          "%DOC%"
        ],
        "env": {"PATH": "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"}
      },
      {
        "name": "pdflatex",
        "command": "pdflatex",
        "args": [
          "-synctex=1",
          "-interaction=nonstopmode",
          "-file-line-error",
          "-outdir=%OUTDIR%",
          "%DOC_EXT%"
        ],
        "env": {"PATH": "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"}
      },
      {
        "name": "bibtex",
        "command": "bibtex",
        "args": [
          "%DOCFILE%"
        ],
        "env": {"PATH": "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"}
      },
    ]


Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue. Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...
